# Android Studio Character set issue in Key alias. How can I solve this?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore

I want to run my app on android studio with release mode.

### The problem is :

There is a one char on key alias in Turkish character set.

And How can I solve this?

### Screenshots

[image]

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: i never released an app but will copy from internet and paste work ?   ü

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### the problem is character set

I solve my issue change **build.gradle** file encoding.

[image]